# Is metaData be changed if i use .NET Obfuscator?

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, obfuscation

I'm basically know about metadata in **c#.net** and I recently heard about .net Obfuscating.
I want to know if I use any obfuscator to make my assemblies from being understood it will obfuscate the IL, but will it also change metadata? Then can I add it as a reference to my project and see the real name for classes and its members?

Comment: Why don't you try? [This](http://ilspy.net/) may also help you.

Comment: I've been using ILspy and i tried to obfuscate one of my Dlls using free edition of .net obfuscator but it said "Dotfuscator Community Edition cannot rename generic types or methods" and failed :(

Comment: Obfuscating is pretty useless for the most part.. what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days most obfuscators can basically rewrite your assembly for you.  The majority of the features include:

Renaming (tool vendors often will provide an option to create a map so you can manually map a renamed member to the original member name with a tool like Reflector)

String encryption - this encrypts string constants in the code (stored in the string heap area of the meatadata) so if you open the file in Reflector it will usually show encrypted.  The encrypted values still get decrypted right before using them.

IL obfuscation - control flow rewriting of the IL to make spaghetti code and difficult to follow

There are also other tools that go way beyond this but they all just raise the bar of what it takes to reverse something.

If you set a reference to an obfuscated dll/exe you'll see the obfuscated/renamed members, but if the vendor provides a map (most will) you can figure out which is which.  You can also typically use interfaces that are not obfuscated if you need a readable api to use.  An example would be Reflector - the addin apis are all interfaces that are not obfuscated but all implementations of the concrete classes are obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Confuser, as there's still no Deobfuscator for this one.

http://confuser.codeplex.com/

You won't see normal names of classes and methods as it hashes them and also many more. It is basically impossible to get anything out of code afterwards.

Comment: Powerful tool, Thanks :)